# why is ifelse function producing NA

Tags: r, if-statement, na

## `ifelse` producing NA

```r
m <- tracking_new_table$CowId=="807439"
ifelse (m==T , tracking_new_table$V1=="8","")
```

I am supposed to get "8" in column VI when the condition is satisfied. Instead I am getting NA´s. In other rows where condition is NOT satisfied, I get "" which is what I wanted.
data

Comment: Hi, please make a [mcve], read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: thanks for the answers! How can I change the codition to check more than one CowId at once, and assing same value(8) to VI?

Comment: See my answer below, but change to: `m <- tracking_new_table$CowID %in% c(807439, 32394)` where you put the `CowID`s inside the concatenated vector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like was pointed out in a comment it is difficult to know exactly what you want without a reproducible example.

It appears you are trying to make an assignment inside of an `ifelse` statement. I am not sure if that is where the problem lies. It could also be that your use of quotation marks around the `CowID` number you are trying to match is causing the problem if `CowID` is of class integer, but by using quotation marks you are turning it into class character.

However, you could do something like this (note that I treat `CowID` as integer/numeric and `V1` as character):

```
tracking_new_table <- data.frame(
  CowID = c(32394, 807439, 967094, 926699),
  V1 = c("", "", "", "")
)

m <- tracking_new_table$CowID == 807439

# This will replace the value in V1
tracking_new_table$V1 <- ifelse(m == T, "8", "")
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably what you need is

```
tracking_new_table$V1 <- ifelse (m, 8,"")
```

which can also be done with

```
tracking_new_table$V1 <- c("", 8)[m + 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

- ifelse returns one of two values, depending on the test condition.
  It's not a flow control function that executes code snippet one or
  code snippet two based on a condition.